# Not filling NaN values in df when using mode of df

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan, fillna

I have this dataframe for which I want to fill in the nan value:

```
quant = ['satisfaction_level', 'last_evaluation', 'average_monthly_hours']
cat = ['number_projects', 'time_spend_company', 'work_accident', 'promotion_last_5_years', 'position', 'salary']
X_train[quant] = X_train[quant].fillna(X_train[quant].median())
X_train[cat] = X_train[cat].fillna(X_train[cat].mode())

X_test[quant] = X_test[quant].fillna(X_test[quant].median())
X_test[cat] = X_test[cat].fillna(X_test[cat].mode())
```

Even when I use .loc instead, it does not fill the NaN and if there are not two modes as the mode()[0] returns an error.

However this does not fill in the categorical nan values though the documentation states that the value parameter can be a dataframe as well: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Other methods such as doing it by column works.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `.mode()` returns a `DataFrame`, so you need to use `.mode().iloc[0]`:

```
for column in cat:
    X_train[column].fillna(X_train[column].mode().iloc[0], inplace=True)
    X_test[column].fillna(X_test[column].mode().iloc[0], inplace=True)
```

This `.mode().iloc[0]` method will not give an error if there are not multiple modes. The `mode()` function always returns a `DataFrame`, even if there is only one mode. The `.iloc[0]` simply selects the first mode from this `DataFrame`. So, if there is only one mode, `.mode().iloc[0]` will return that mode. If there are multiple modes, `.mode().iloc[0]` will return the first one.
When you use `.mode()[0]` on a `pandas.DataFrame`, it can lead to issues if there are not multiple modes. This is because `.mode()` returns a `DataFrame`, and when you use `[0]`, it tries to access the first column of this `DataFrame`, not the first row.

I tested this snipped with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_train = pd.DataFrame({
    'satisfaction_level': [0.38, 0.80, 0.11, 0.72, 0.37, np.nan],
    'last_evaluation': [0.53, 0.86, 0.88, 0.87, 0.52, 0.50],
    'average_monthly_hours': [157, np.nan, 272, 223, 159, 153],
    'number_projects': [2, 5, 7, 5, 2, np.nan],
    'time_spend_company': [3, 6, 4, 5, 3, 3],
    'work_accident': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    'promotion_last_5_years': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'position': ['sales', 'sales', 'sales', 'sales', 'sales', np.nan],
    'salary': ['low', 'medium', 'medium', 'low', 'low', 'low']
})

df_test = pd.DataFrame({
    'satisfaction_level': [0.41, 0.10, 0.92, 0.89, 0.42, 0.45],
    'last_evaluation': [0.50, 0.77, 0.85, 0.91, 0.53, np.nan],
    'average_monthly_hours': [160, 255, 262, 234, 158, 145],
    'number_projects': [2, 6, 5, 5, 2, 2],
    'time_spend_company': [3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2],
    'work_accident': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    'promotion_last_5_years': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'position': ['sales', 'sales', 'sales', 'sales', 'sales', 'sales'],
    'salary': ['low', 'medium', 'medium', 'low', 'low', np.nan]
})

quant = ['satisfaction_level', 'last_evaluation', 'average_monthly_hours']
cat = ['number_projects', 'time_spend_company', 'work_accident', 'promotion_last_5_years', 'position', 'salary']

# Fill NaN values in quantitative columns with median
df_train[quant] = df_train[quant].fillna(df_train[quant].median())
df_test[quant] = df_test[quant].fillna(df_test[quant].median())

# Fill NaN values in categorical columns with mode
for column in cat:
    df_train[column].fillna(df_train[column].mode().iloc[0], inplace=True)
    df_test[column].fillna(df_test[column].mode().iloc[0], inplace=True)

print(df_train)
print(df_test)
```

|  | satisfaction_level | last_evaluation | average_monthly_hours | number_projects | time_spend_company | work_accident | promotion_last_5_years | position | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.38 | 0.53 | 157 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | sales | low |
| 1 | 0.8 | 0.86 | 159 | 5 | 6 | 0 | 0 | sales | medium |
| 2 | 0.11 | 0.88 | 272 | 7 | 4 | 0 | 0 | sales | medium |
| 3 | 0.72 | 0.87 | 223 | 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 | sales | low |
| 4 | 0.37 | 0.52 | 159 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | sales | low |
| 5 | 0.38 | 0.5 | 153 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | sales | low |

|  | satisfaction_level | last_evaluation | average_monthly_hours | number_projects | time_spend_company | work_accident | promotion_last_5_years | position | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.41 | 0.5 | 160 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | sales | low |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.77 | 255 | 6 | 4 | 0 | 0 | sales | medium |
| 2 | 0.92 | 0.85 | 262 | 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 | sales | medium |
| 3 | 0.89 | 0.91 | 234 | 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 | sales | low |
| 4 | 0.42 | 0.53 | 158 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | sales | low |
| 5 | 0.45 | 0.77 | 145 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | sales | low |